# Opencv GUI python: arrange the created buttons

Tags: python, opencv

I use python 3.8 and Opencv in Linux.

1. I have several buttons that have stacked horizontally. How can I arrange them as I like (e.g., in a grid way?)
2. Is it possible to show some icons for each of the buttons?
3. Is it possible to make the fonts of the buttons bar larger?

Part of my script: (any suggestion to make my script better is appreciated)

```
if __name__== "__main__":


    Folder_name = "male"
    data_path = "path/to/images"
    data_path = os.path.join(data_path, Folder_name)

    all_imgs_path = glob.glob("{}/*.jpg".format(data_path))
    all_imgs_path = sorted(all_imgs_path)
    annot = annotation_tool(nof_imgs=len(all_imgs_path))

    for index, im_dir in enumerate(all_imgs_path):
        annot[index] = im_dir

    item_path = "guid.jpg"
    img = cv2.imread(item_path)
    img_name = item_path.split("/")[-1]
    cv2.imshow("{}".format(img_name), img)

    cv2.createButton('Next', annot.Next, ["Next Image"])
    cv2.createButton('Back', annot.Back, ["Previous Image"])
    cv2.createButton('Submit', annot.Submit, ["Submit"])

     # there are many of these buttons
    UB_Tshirt = cv2.createButton("UB_Tshirt", annot.checkbox, "UB_Tshirt", 1, 0)
    UB_Shirt = cv2.createButton("UB_Shirt", annot.checkbox, "UB_Shirt", 1, 0)
    UB_Coat = cv2.createButton("UB_Coat", annot.checkbox, "UB_Coat", 1, 0)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    print("end")
```

Edit:

As you see in the image, the buttons bar is very long and goes out of the screen. I would like to create a button pad that is squared.
[image]

Comment: are you asking how to compute what the x, y values _should_ be, how to do the math to determine the x, y values, or how to specify the x, y values?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Paul H. As you see in the uploaded image, the buttons bar is very long and goes out of the screen. I would like to create a button pad that is squared, with larger fonts, and possibly with some icons.

Comment: i understand what you want. what i'm asking you to do is define the barrier to achieving that. are you asking "how do i to specify positions of the buttons?", or "how do i determine the positions of that buttons?" ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, but in regards to button arrangement, you have a little control using 'cv2.QT_NEW_BUTTONBAR'.

There's further detail here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html#gad15c7adb377e778dc907c0e318be193e